# Android AsyncHttpClient POST JSON Data to web service

Tags: android, json, androidhttpclient

I am try to send this piece of JSON data to my web service, the web service does not capture the JSON data.

```
{"address":{"city":"Sydney","Country":"Australia"}}
```

This is the code which i use to send data from Android.

```
JSONObject addressData= new JSONObject();
    try {
        addressData.put("city", "Sydney");
        addressData.put("Country", "Australia");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

JSONObject JsonString = new JSONObject();
    JsonString.put("Address", addressData);

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JsonString.toString());

AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
httpClient.post(getApplicationContext(),"URL", entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response)         {
super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
System.out.println("response: " + response);
}
@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {

            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.e("msg", content);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), content,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
});
```

The server does not receive the JSON DATA.

Comment: Do you have some logs ? Is there a response from the server (even an error) ?

Comment: on logcat i get this  `response body is null, calling onFailure(Throwable, JSONObject)`

Comment: Where is the onFailure method ?

Comment: even if there is onFailure method the onFailure is not called.
I modified question with onFailure

Answer (score -1):

Use `RequestParams` to send data to the server.

Check the section `Adding GET/POST Parameters with RequestParams` of the [main page](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Comment: I want to send JSON objects